# Was there a molecular test of Lanciano and Buenos Aires Eucharistic miracles?

Tags: biology, religion, miracle

Some roman catholic sources like this March 2012 US Roman Catholic Journal article [This Is My Body–This Is My Blood](http://www.catholicjournal.us/2012/03/30/this-is-my-body-this-is-my-blood/)
claim there was an investigation performed about the [eucharistic miracles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucharistic_miracle) in [Lanciano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_of_Lanciano) (around 700) and Buenos Aires ([Google search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=eucharistic+miracle+Buenos+Aires+1996)) (1996). This investigation showed that the flesh that appeared there contains identical DNA. They also point to certain Doctor Ricardo Castanon Gomez that was atheist before the tests but turned catholic later.

Is there any independent source that these tests were performed and that abovementioned doctor was really an atheist biologist that was drawn to faith by his investigation?

Comment: [Ricerche istologiche, immunologiche e biochimiche sulla carne e sul sangue del miracolo eucaristico di Lanciano (VII secolo)](http://www.unilibro.it/libro/linoli-odoardo/ricerche-istologiche-immunologiche-biochimiche-carne-sangue-miracolo-eucaristico-lanciano-vii-secolo-/9788887316025) is the book written by Odoardo Linoli, the doctor that did the research on Lanciano. Linoli *was* a professor. He concluded that the relics *are* flesh and blood from the heart of a human being with AB blood type. No idea about Buenos Aires though.

Comment: In any case, you might be interested in atheist [Jacalyn Duffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackie_Duffin) who did the scientific studies that the Vatican requested for the canonization of Marie-Marguerite D'Youville. She wrote [an article for the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/religion/0/24660240).  So if you are skeptical that the Vatican performs serious scientific tests before declaring a Miracle etc *you are wrong*. Obviously the test cannot result in "yes, the law of physics failed in VII centery, so it's a miracle", they can only describe the final result and try to provide explanations.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I am not sceptical about Vatican's scepticism. I am just talking about this one case which seems to be an urban legend copypasta that found its way to several roman catholic blogs. Nothing about Vatican here, as I never found any statement from Vatican about these tests.